# Receive values directly from the command line

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

What I'm attempting to do is receive values from the command line (instead of using the read method and asking the user to enter the values and/or file names in multiple steps).

```
./hello.sh 5 15 <file_name.txt
```

I have heard that simply using an array can help do the same, but I am not able to-

1. Avoid printing

   ```
   5 15
   ```

   on the next line
2. Since 5 and 15 are being printed, I'd expect the string 'abcdefgh' (contents of file_name.txt) to be printed; however, the output stops at

   ```
   5 15
   ```

I would really appreciate it if someone could point out why my code isn't sufficient, and if possible, point me in the direction of some learning resources to broaden my knowledge of this concept.

Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

echo "$@"
```

I am simply testing things out (wanted to print out the variables before doing anything with and to them).

Comment: Command line arguments can be accessed within your script using `$1`, `$2`, etc. Could you add the contents of `hello.sh` to your question?

Comment: On using @Cole Tierney's suggestion, I have been able to print 5 and 15. It seems that using $3 to access file_name.txt isn't the right way to go about it.

Comment: `file_name.txt` is not being passed as a parameter. The `<` character is making the file contents available to the script via standard input, which means its contents would be accessed using `read` in this case.

Comment: How about `./hello.sh 5 15 $(cat file_name.txt)`

Comment: @James Brown It works pretty well! Thank you very much! On a side note, would it be possible for me to add something to hello.sh to expect a redirection from a file?

Comment: @Cole Tierney Your second comment perfectly solved my issue, thanks a lot! (sorry, didn't see your comment until after I replied to James Brown).

Comment: @AdvaitaMallik The script can't really tell if its input has been redirected. If it tries to read from standard input (e.g. with the `read` command), by default it'll read from the Terminal (i.e. wait for the user to type something in), but if input was redirected it'll read from the file instead.

Comment: Modify hello.sh to understand that the third parameter is a file: make 2 lines. The first says `echo $1 $2` and the second says `cat $3`.

Answer (score 1):

`<file_name.txt` is a redirection. It is **not** passed as a parameter. The parameters of the script are `5` and `15`. The `<` *redirects* the file `file_name.txt` to *standard input stdin* of the script. You can read from *stdin* with for example `cat`.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "$@"  # outputs parameters of the script joined with spaces
cat        # redirects standard input to standard output, i.e. reads from the fiel
```

> why my code isn't sufficient

Your script is not reading from the file, so the content of the file is ignored.

> point me in the direction of some learning resources

File descriptors and redirections and standard streams are basic tools in shell - you should learn about them in any shell and linux introduction. My 5 min google search resulted in this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-i-o-redirection , which looks like some introduction to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
./hello.sh 5 15 `catfile_name.txt`
```

And update `hello.sh` to:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
shift 2
echo $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic solution. It looks at each input parameter in turn. If it is a valid file, it outputs the contents of the file. Otherwise if just prints the parameter.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

for $parameter in "${@}"; do   # Quotation marks avoid splitting parameters with spaces.
  if [ -f $parameter ]; then   # '-f {value}' tests if {value} is a file. 
    cat $parameter
  else
    echo $parameter            # You could also use 'echo -n ...' to skip newlines.
  fi
done
```